# Rendering models renders an empty object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

```html
<head>
   <title><%=@article.title%></title>
</head>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col"></div>
   <div class="col-6">
      <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center"><%= @article.title %></h1>
      <p><%= @article.text %></p>
      <div class= "d-flex justify-content-center">
         <%= render 'comments/form'%>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      <%= render  @article.comments %>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header"><%= if(!comment.nil?) then comment.commenter end %></div>
   <div class="card-body"><%= if(!comment.nil?) then  comment.body end %></div>
</div>
```

This always renders an additional empty card (or empty whatever I use in there) and I don't know why. It doesn't do that, if I don't have it in the very right column of bootstrap but in the middle??? I have no idea what's going wrong here and after like 2 hours this is my last resort.

EDIT: The issue was in rendering form, i had comment.build in it which apparently creates an empty object in RAM to be rendered by rails. I changed it to:
`<%= form_with model: [@article, Comment], local:true do |form| %>`

Comment: Can you also update controller action code in question?

Comment: The controller only loads (at)article (to which the comments belong).
Comment model: belongs_to :article
Article model: has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
Controller loads (at)article = Article.find(params[:id])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're asking but the card divs will always render whether you have a comment or not, creating an empty card if they are not there.

Change this:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header"><%= if(!comment.nil?) then comment.commenter end %></div>
  <div class="card-body"><%= if(!comment.nil?) then  comment.body end %></div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<% if (!comment.nil?) %>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header"><%= comment.commenter %></div>
  <div class="card-body"><%= comment.body %></div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And then the card divs will only generate when `comment` exists, removing that empty card.

Comment: Well this helped with the if structure, apparently I messed that up in my previous tries... Anyway only .nil? doesn't help, but I added checks for commenter and body .nil? and now it works